# First-child and last-child in separate containers

Tags: html, css, containers, pseudo-element

Can I apply the first-child and last-child pseudo elements to the divs with the same class that are in different sub-containers? In the example below, div with the classes "box selected" are all stored under "1st-container", but there are 2 additional containers on the way:

```
<div class="1st-container">
    <div class="2nd-container">
        <div class="3rd-container">
            <div class="box selected">  // this div should have first-child pseudo elements
            <div class="box">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="2nd-container">
        <div class="3rd-container">
            <div class="box selected">
            <div class="box">
            <div class="box">
            <div class="box">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="2nd-container">
        <div class="3rd-container">
            <div class="box selected">  // this div should have last-child pseudo 
            <div class="box">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is that doable with pure css?

Comment: There is no `:first-of-class` pseudo.

Comment: This won't work, because they are first children of their parent divs.

Comment: create a firstchild and a lastchild class with the wanted characteristics, and assign them to the elements.

Comment: Can you write a css rule how you would "like it to look/work like" and we try make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot use numbers to start classes or id's.

Secondly, you just need to do a find on the first and last child of the second element in and you should be able to find the elements you need.

```css
.box {
  height: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  background: blue;
}
.box.selected {
  background: red;
}
.two-container:first-child .box.selected,
.two-container:last-child .box.selected {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="one-container">
  <div class="two-container">
    <div class="three-container">
      <div class="box selected">// this div should have first-child pseudo elements</div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="two-container">
    <div class="three-container">
      <div class="box selected"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="two-container">
    <div class="three-container">
      <div class="box selected">// this div should have last-child pseudo</div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic, it did the trick. I was roaming around, but never thought of putting the pseudo-elements to a container div (I was trying on different variations of `.box.selected:first-child`)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do what you've described, because in both cases, `"box selected"` is the first child of its parent. You could take a different approach, though. For example, you could target those two divs like so:

```
.2nd-container:first-child .selected, 
.2nd-container:last-child .selected 
{}
```

*As pointed out, replace the `2` with a non-digit, as that won't work. I was distracted by the main question. :-)*

Comment: Thanks Ralph but the snag is that the number of "2nd-container"s will vary, it can be 3 of them, it can be 123. Thanks anyway

Comment: It doesn't matter how many there are, as long as it's the first and last you want to target.

Answer (score 0):

with JS it looks easier than CSS:

```
var selected = document.querySelectorAll('.one-container .box.selected');

selected[0].style.background = selected[selected.length-1].style.background='green';
```

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/uL54rju9/)